# django server sharing scope with celery workers

Tags: python, django, celery

I am working on a web application that uses a permanent object MyService. Using a web interface I am dynamically updating its state and monitor its behavior. Now I would like to periodically call one of its methods. I was thinking of using celery PeriodicTask but run into some scope issues. It seems I need to execute three different processes:

```
python manage.py runserver
python manage.py celery worker
python manage.py celerybeat
```

The problem is that even if I ensure that MyService is a singleton that can be safely used by more than one thread, celery creates its own fresh copy of the object. Is there a way I could share this object between both django server and celery main process? I tried to find a way to start celery from within django script but until now with no success. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to share something between multiple processes or maybe even multiple machines (eg. your workers could run on a seperate machine) the best (and probably easiest) practice to share information would be using an external service.

In the simplest case you could use Django's DB, but if you encounter that this is not suitable for you, for example if you have a heavy write load you can use something like Redis or Memcache (which you can also talk to via Django's caching API). These will enable you to be able to handle a big write load and besides you can use eg. Redis as a queue for celery as well.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the way to pass simple static data around. Unfortunately MyService is more than a simple data storage, it is supposed to spawn new threads with a callback function. I think I will run it as a brand new service and let django communicate with it using sockets directly.

Comment: I don't know what it's supposed to do exactly, but for a safe way to communicate with something like that you could also look into redis pubsub or a message queue like 0mq.